# Microsoft Lync 2010 SDK. Not receiving instant messaging events

Tags: c#, events, lync-2010, lync

I have a test application using the Lync 2010 SDK in full UI suppressed mode. I am trying to build a simple instant-messaging client. I can send messages/text okay (for example to a non UI suppressed Microsoft Lync 2010 client), but I cannot receive any messages. By that I mean the events `IsTypeChanged` and `InstantMessageReceived` are not raised. They do get raised, however, when the test app sends messages.

Is there anything that I am missing to allow messages to pass?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your app - can you post up the code you're using?

Comment: I apologize. Kind of solved the problem. I realized that I was not subscribing the SelfParticipant Modality to the events. I didn't see it initially because this behavior is slightly different handling from the Audio/Video modalities. Thank you anyway though.